# Terser: Only mangle matched property names from regex

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, rollup, terser

I want to keep ALL my variables and function names, even the private ones, and only mangles the ones that match the regex.

[The docs say](https://github.com/terser/terser#mangle-properties-options):

> `regex` (default: null) — Pass a RegExp literal or pattern string to
> only mangle property matching the regular expression.

But this will also mangles all private const in function scope like so:
(`keep_fnames` and `keep_classnames` are set to `true`).

Config:

```
const terserOptions = {
  compress: {
    defaults: false,
  },
  format: {
    beautify: true,
    comments: "all",
  },
  mangle: {
    keep_fnames: true,
    properties: {
      regex: /^_/,
    },
  },
};
```

Input:

```
function myFunc(arg) {
  const keepThisVarName = arg * 2;
  return {
    keepThisProp: keepThisVarName,
    _mangleThisOne: keepThisVarName,
  }
}
```

Output:

```
function myFunc(e) {
  const t = 2 * e;
  return {
    keepThisProp: t,
    p: t
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
function myFunc(arg) {
  const keepThisVarName = arg * 2;
  return {
    keepThisProp: keepThisVarName,
    p: keepThisVarName, // '_mangleThisOne' should be mangled
  }
}
```

Am I missing something or is it simply not possible to prevent Terser to mangle everything he can by default?
If not, any ideas how to mangle only variables that match a regular expression and keep the rest of my codebase intact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source, code it doesn't seem possible to prevent mangling private methods when using the mangle option. Terser will always run `mangle_private_properties()` when `mangle` is defined.

```
if (options.mangle) {
    toplevel.compute_char_frequency(options.mangle);
    toplevel.mangle_names(options.mangle);
    toplevel = mangle_private_properties(toplevel, options.mangle);
}
```

https://github.com/terser/terser/blob/a47f29a57b12999c939845781daa7d6f8bdaeff2/lib/minify.js#L264

Answer (score 0):

I think that may be just regular minification happening (local scoped variables are usually minified)

---

I don't know for certain, but my reasoning is that I think mangling has to do with the object keys only; for all the compiler knows, you may be dynamically constructing a plain text key like `keepThisProp` and trying to access it on the object at a later time